# Search response time doubled erratically

Tags: performance, search, elasticsearch

Our system recently faced a CPU usage spike and the underlying reason is still unknown. We have faced high memory usage and disk alerts in the past, since we run a nightly job of bulk indexing, updating almost all our docs. But high CPU usage has not been a problem.

The data collected so far:

Node 03 (out of 6 data nodes and 3 master) suffered from high CPU usage (> 95%) for 5 minutes, resulting in a response time spike of 1 sec, while the average response time is 40 ms.
Looking through the metrics, there was a slight bump in the indexing count on the given high CPU node, at the same time, there was a slight bump in Young GC (nothing like a spike though, in both cases).

I am not ruling out heavy indexing, since we do have a kafka consumer accepting bulk indexing data any time of data, but that is controlled at a speed of max 250 docs per second with a lag time of 250 ms between each bulk call.

Also, the hot threads endpoint did give some data, although I am not able to decipher it yet.

[Hot threads](https://gist.github.com/utmishra/76a0a26382b54057d72d9bc5534ed54c)

**Update**

**Updated the question title since previous observations were wrong. Major concern is doubled response time and not high CPU usage, since usage got stabilised after a while.**

There has been some development. After the spike, CPU usage decreased gradually and is normal.
However, our response time is consistently staying between 100-250 ms (Usual average - 35-100 ms).

There is a near-to-toothsaw (not exactly a uniform toothsaw ) pattern in the response currently.

[image: Response time]

Also, there was a small bump in old GC count when the spike occurred.

Haven't found any anomaly in the node stats. Will update when found. Still posting for investigation.

[node stats](https://gist.github.com/utmishra/1685e4fd10109c827b0d75d5419cf633)

Also posting the recent hot thread -

[hot_thread_2](https://gist.github.com/utmishra/2a66dca1912655e12db91caa7e2fc0aa)

Comment: If you have access to logs, check what kind of of queries you ran during the cpu spike. Sorting results is Cpu intensive. You might be running queries which returned a huge number of results. Just a guess...

Comment: @jay We have a business logic setup with hard coded result size values. Also checked the logs for any anamoly. Couldn't find anything.

Comment: All the hot threads are search related. Did u take the hot threads dump during the spike? Were there any changes in your queries? Aggregations? If you have any monitoring setup on these servers, can you check if Node 03 was undergoing a heavy merge at the time of spike?

Comment: @jay No heavy search queries were occurring during the spike. As you can see in the updated question, My primary concern is the raised response time, which is double of usual.

Answer (score 0):

Node 03 definitely seems to have undergone heavy indexing.

```
                "bulk": {
                "threads": 8,
                "queue": 0,
                "active": 0,
                "rejected": 0,
                "largest": 8,
                "completed": 9528532
```

I compared Node 04 stats with Node 03. A few more things I noticed on 03.

- 4144165 docs but 256087749 (index_total) indexing requests?
- Only Node 03 has 41 open_contexts. So it has 41 search requests at the time you took this stat. All other nodes are 0.
- Number of merges for Node 03 and Node 01 is very very high compared to other nodes.

Do you have any routing logic which sends specific documents to specific nodes? Or may be these nodes contain indices which are updated a lot more often?

Also by any chance did u or your application issue a optimize on the index on Node 03 when you saw the spike? Looking at the node stats, 03 is the only node which has a "completed" optimize

```
"optimize": {
                "threads": 1,
                "queue": 0,
                "active": 0,
                "rejected": 0,
                "largest": 1,
                "completed": 1
            },
```

also, what is your refresh_interval? Default in ES is 1 second. Which might trigger a lot of merges while bulk indexing.

Comment: The increased number of indexing requests could be because we have a midnight job updating almost all of our docs. Also, we don't have a logic currently to route the search requests currently. Currently, we send all search requests to the first 3 nodes. 
Besides, our bulk indexing runs mostly during midnight, and we're okay if search response goes up during the time. Current refresh_interval is set as 1 second.

Comment: Regarding the routing issue. I doubt that only 1 node would be receiving all search requests though. While we don't have proper routing logic, our application server sends requests to the nodes based on availability. Even so, we don't have as many search request that should hog any single node.